# How to display the “Menu Title” in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, menu

I’m trying to display the menu title text (example “Home”) in the header area of my Joomla 2.5 website.

Joomla’s default (when activated) is to place it in the Component area.

I’m not sure the best way to accomplish this. By default Joomla wraps the menu title with an H1 tag but doesn’t wrap it with a div and class.

The ways I’ve thought might be best to do this are:

- Somehow wrap all menu titles with a div and class so I could reposition them up into the header with css .
- Add some php code to my template. Something like:

  php
      $menuTitle =  $this->params->get(‘fieldNameOfMenuTitle’);

  php
       echo = $menuTitle;

Any ideas, suggestions, or answers would greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never found an exact answer but found a work around.

Used a modified version of the below demo/plug-in to create a custom field (named it: "Title that displays on the Web Page") in the articles menu. By default, the table that is created and displayed in the web page is in the component area and is wrapped in a  w/ a class. Repositioned the  with CSS up into the header/banner area.

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component